# Distinct & compact word lists to represent e.g. fingerprints or other binary data for humans?

Tags: cryptography, communication, word-list

What word lists / "dictionaries" can you suggest for conveying binary data such as cryptographic fingerprints, hashes etc. ?

Criteria for such a word list are e.g.

- Compact, i.e. a long list of rather short words so you need less of those words to transmit data
- Distinctive words / simple to distinguish (no homonyms, not even accidentally caused by slight mispronunciation)
- Simple to spell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most familiar ones is the [PGP word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list).